# How did this method get the correct answer? Product of divisors

Tags: number-theory

Find the product of the divisors of $420^4$.

$420^4=2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 7^4$. I tried the following method which I soon realized was flawed: for $2^8$ there are $5^3$ possible divisors, for $2^7$ there are also $5^3$ and so on... for $3^4$ there are $9 \cdot 5^2$ possible divisors and for $3^3$ and so on and so forth.

Though I seem to be over-counting the powers loads here, e.g. I will count any one divisor maybe four times. But I still get the answer as $420^{2250}$ which is correct, how can this be?

And yes I know the formula for working out the product easily.

Comment: You're not even counting whole divisors.  You're counting the exponent of each of the four prime divisors which occurs in the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's just a coincidence of the fact that you're computing the product of the divisors of $n^{\ell}$ for a number $n$ that has $\ell$ distinct prime factors.

Set $n=420$ and $m=420^4$.  If by the statement "for $2^8$ there are $5^3$ possible divisors" you mean that there are $5^3$ possible divisors of $m$ of the form $2^8 \cdot s$ for an integer $s$, then yes, this will over-count the number of divisors $d$ of $m$ by a factor of $4$.  So your count is $c = 4d$.

I suspect all you did was compute $n^{c/2}$ rather than $m^{d/2}$.  But $n^{c/2} = n^{4d/2} = (n^4)^{d/2} = m^{d/2}$.

This generalizes.  If $n$ has the prime factorization $n=\prod_{i=1}^{\ell} p_i^{a_i}$ then
$$
c:=\prod_{i=1}^{\ell} (a_i + 1) = \ell \cdot d
$$
where $d$ is the number of divisors of $n$.  Then of course the product of all the divisors of $n^{\ell}$ is just $n^{c/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing seems to be correct, although your procedure is a bit ad hoc.

Let me try to formalize your method: in general, if $x = p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} ... p_k^{n_k}$ with $p_i$ distinct primes and $n_i>0$, the product of all factors will be of the form $p_1^{K_1}\dots p_n^{K_n}$ for some $K_i >0$. The crux of the matter is to determine the $K_i$'s. Note that $K_i$ will be the sum over all factors of $x$ of the exponent of $p_i$ appearing in the factor.

This is, I think, what you are getting at when you write "for $2^8$ there are $5^3$...". You're saying that factors divisible by $2^8$ will contribute $8\cdot 5^3$ to the exponent of $2$ in the product of all factors. Factors divisible by $2^7$ but not $2^8$ will contribute $7*5^3$, and so forth. Summing all these, you get $(1+2+3+4+...+8)(5^3)$ for the exponent of $2$. The way that you've enumerated things, nothing is double counted.

Returning to the general set up, factors of $x$ are precisely numbers of the form $p_1^mt$, for $t$ a factor of $p_2^{n_2}\dots p_k^{n_k}$ and $0 \leq m \leq n_1$. If we let $M$ equal the number of factors of $p_2^{n_2}\dots p_k^{n_k}$, we have that $$K_1=M(\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}i) = M\frac{n_1(n_1+1)}{2}.$$ In your case, if $p_1=2$ and $n_1=8$, you calculate that $M= 5^3$. This is correct: in general, $M$, the number of factors of $p_2^{n_2}\dots p_k^{n_k}$, is $(n_2+1)\dots (n_k+1)$. Generalizing this argument to other indices,

$$K_j = \frac{(\prod_{i=1}^k n_i+1)(n_j)}{2},$$

which is the formula that you know. So your method can actually be used to construct a (much longer) proof of the formula.

Hope this helps clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

Call $n=420^4$, $D = \{ \mbox{divisors of }n\}$ and $d=\#D$.
Then $$
\left(\prod_{a \in D} a\right)^2 = \prod_{a \in D} a * \prod_{a \in D} \frac{n}{a} = n^d
$$

So the answer is $n^{d/2}$.

Finally, computing $d=9*5*5*5 = 1125$, you get that the product of the divisors of $n$ is $420^{2250}$.

Comment: Sorry but did you read my post? I know the formula, I was just wondering why an apparently flawed method gave the correct answer as it seems to me that it should have given a completely wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

> $420^4 =2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 7^4$. I tried the following method which I soon realized was flawed: for $2^8$ there are $5^3$ possible divisors, for $2^7$ there are also $5^3$ and so on... for $3^4$ there are $9⋅5^2$ possible divisors and for $3^3$ and so on and so forth.
>
> Though I seem to be over-counting the powers loads here, e.g. I will count any one divisor maybe four times. But I still get the answer as $420^{2250}$ which is correct, how can this be?

Why do you think *this* method is flawed?  You want to count the **product** of **all** the divisors of the number, so of course you're counting the same prime divisors multiple times.

Let's simplify the example.  Find the product of the divisors of $18$.

The divisors of $18$ are: $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18\}$ which is: $\{2^0 3^0, 2^1 3^0, 2^0 3^1, 2^1 3^1, 2^0 3^2, 2^1 3^2\}$

Clearly each power of $2$ occurs thrice, and each power of $3$ occurs twice.

So the product is: $$\begin{align} & \quad (2^0 \times 2^1)^3 \times (3^0 \times 3^1 \times 3^2)^2\\ & = 2^{(0+1)\times 3}\cdot 3^{(0+1+2)\times 2} \\ & = 2^3 3^6 \\ & = 18^3\end{align}$$

Thus by this method, the product of the divisors of $420^4$ is: $$\large \begin{align} & \quad\quad 2^{\frac{8\times 9}2\times 5^3}3^{\frac{4\times 5}2\times 9\times 5^2}5^{\frac{4\times 5}2\times 9\times 5^2}7^{\frac{4\times 5}2\times 9\times 5^2} \\ & = (2^2\times 3\times 5\times 7)^{2\times 9\times 5^3} \\ & = 420^{2250}\end{align}$$

---

In general, take any cardinal $n$, such that $n= \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}$ where $\{p_1, \ldots p_r\}$ are the prime divisors of $n$, and $\{a_1, \ldots, a_r\}$ are their exponents.

Let $\pi(n)$ be the product of the divisors of $n$.  The number of times a prime divisor ($p_i$) appears in $\pi(n)$ will be $\frac {a_i} 2 \sum_{j=1}^r (a_j+1)$.  (As shown above.)  So thus:

$$\begin{align}\pi(\prod_{i=1}^r p_i) & = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\frac {a_i} 2 \sum_{j=1}^r (a_j+1)} \\ & = \left(\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}\right)^{\frac 12 \prod_{j=1}^r (a_j+1)} \\ \therefore \pi(n) & = n ^{\frac 12 \prod_{j=1}^r (a_j+1)} \end{align}$$

Now we know that $\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{j=1}^r (a_j+1)$ is the **count** of whole divisors of $n$.  So we have: $$\pi(n) = n^{\sigma_0(n)/2}$$

$$\boxed{\begin{align}\because \sigma_0(2^8 3^4 5^4 7^4) & =(8+1)(4+1)^3 \\ & = 1125 \\ \therefore \pi(420^4) &= (420^4)^{1125/2} \\ & = 420^{2250}\end{align}}$$

Comment: If I understood things correctly, the poster wasn't concerned about over-counting prime divisors but rather the divisors themselves.

Comment: You're correct Shawn